# Can I use get the just insert table row id, from mysql_query?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: how to get last inserted ID of a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/php-how-to-get-last-inserted-id-of-a-table)

I use `mysql_query()` in PHP to insert a new record in my Database.

It will auto generate a row, with a user Id, can I use the result to get that Id?

Comment: Do you mean it will auto generate a row, not a table?

Answer (score 3):

#### [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Have you considered upgrading to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)?