# Return a value from an INSERT query in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: how to get last inserted ID of a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/php-how-to-get-last-inserted-id-of-a-table)

This is my query for inserting a new post into the posts table (PHP/mysql). Can I return the post_id for the post just inserted in the same statement? I need the post_id for insertion into another table.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `posts` (`post_id`, `date`, `title`, `content`) VALUES (NULL,    NOW(), '$title', '$fileName')");
```

Comment: @Michael typo in first comment `mysql_insert_id()` or `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `posts` (`date`, `title`, `content`) VALUES (NOW(), '$title', '$fileName')");
$last_inserted = mysql_insert_id(); // return last inserted id
```

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) will give you the last ID

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what the MySQL function last_insert_id() is for. So, essentially the answer is, "no, but kinda". You need to execute an additional query "select last_insert_id()", which will return 1 row, with your ID in it.