# Auto_increment in 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, forms, auto-increment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: how to get last inserted ID of a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/php-how-to-get-last-inserted-id-of-a-table)

I made a form and want to write data in two tables.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ma_forum (notcat_id, usr_id, not_titulo, not_status, not_tags, not_data, not_comentarios, not_resumo, not_texto) 

        VALUES('$categoria', '".$_SESSION[usr_name]."', '$titulo', '$status', '$tags', '".time()."', '$comentarios', '$resumo', '$texto')";

$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$sql_or = "INSERT INTO ma_forum_comentarios (comnot_habbo, comnot_data, comnot_status) VALUES('$_SESSION[usr_name]', '".time()."', '$status_comnot')";

$res = mysql_query($sql_or) or die(mysql_error());
```

But in the first table it writes the ID automatically auto_increment. But I would like to enter the ID of the first table and another column. Anyone know how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the php function mysql_insert_id() to retrieve the last id inserted: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

So it should be:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ma_forum (notcat_id, usr_id, not_titulo, not_status, not_tags, not_data, not_comentarios, not_resumo, not_texto) VALUES ('$categoria', '".$_SESSION[usr_name]."', '$titulo', '$status', '$tags', '".time()."', '$comentarios', '$resumo', '$texto')";

$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$sql_or = "INSERT INTO ma_forum_comentarios (id, comnot_habbo, comnot_data, comnot_status) VALUES(" . mysql_insert_id() . ",'$_SESSION[usr_name]', '".time()."', '$status_comnot')";

$res = mysql_query($sql_or) or die(mysql_error());
```

Make sure you replace the 'id' column I specified with your actual id column name.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```