# how to retrieve id from first insert in order to use in second insert

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Below I have an INSERT database function using php and mysqli:

```
for ($i = 1, $n = $_SESSION['sessionNum']; $i <= $n; $i++) {

        $insertsql = "
  INSERT INTO Session
    (SessionName, SessionTime, SessionDate, SessionWeight, SessionDuration, TotalMarks, ModuleId, TeacherId, Room)
  VALUES
    (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
";
if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($insertsql)) {
  // Handle errors with prepare operation here
}

    $sessname = $_SESSION['id'] . ($n == 1 ? '' : $i);
    $sessdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_SESSION['dateChosen']));

    $insert->bind_param("sssisiiis", $sessname, $_SESSION['timeChosen'], $sessdate,
                 $_SESSION['totalWeight'], $time, $_SESSION['textMarks'],
                 $_SESSION['hiddenmodule'], $teacherid, $_SESSION['rooms']);

    $insert->execute();

    if ($insert->errno) {
      // Handle query error here
    }

    $insert->close();

}
```

The above code will insert this data in the database below as an example in one go:

```
SessionId (Auto) SessionName  SessionTime  //etc
1                ADFGR1       01:00:00
2                ADFGR2       13:00:00
3                ADFGR2       09:00:00
```

Anyway you can see I have not include `SessionId` in the code above as it is an auto increment meaning that it is going to be displayed anyway.

But the problem I have is that underneath this insert, what I want to do is that when the above insert is finished, I want to do another insert underneath:

```
        $insertsession = "
  INSERT INTO Session_Complete
    (SessionId)
  VALUES
    (?)
";
if (!insertdb = $mysqli->prepare($insertsession)) {
  // Handle errors with prepare operation here
}


    insertdb->bind_param("i",$value);

    insertdb->execute();

    if (insertdb->errno) {
      // Handle query error here
    }
```

But the problem I have with the above insert is that it requires the already inserted `SessionId`'s from the first insert in order to insert those ids into its table. My question is how do I retrieve the `SessionId` from the first insert so I can include them in the second insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be this:

```
$insert->insert_id;
```

Comment: so do I put something like `$lastID = $insert->insert_id;` and then store `$lastID` in the bind_param() for the second insert?

Answer (score 2):

if you want, you can use `TRIGGER` on this, eg.

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger_Name` 
  AFTER INSERT ON `Session`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Session_Complete (SessionId) values (LAST_INSERT_ID());
END$$
delimiter ;
```

What the trigger does is after a successful insert on table `Session`, it will also insert the last inserted ID on table `Session_Complete`.

Comment: Wow. You are like our DBA who would actually prefer a `SELECT httpResponse( requestURI )` :) kidding, this is a fine solution as long as the OP has the privileges to create triggers.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [How do I get the last inserted ID of a MySQL table in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/php-how-to-get-last-inserted-id-of-a-table) to get the last insert ID after the insert to `Session` and use that value in your following insert into `Session_Complete`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MySQL function [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).

> LAST_INSERT_ID() (with no argument) returns a BIGINT (64-bit) value representing the first automatically generated value successfully inserted for an AUTO_INCREMENT column as a result of the most recently executed INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

Like with other tables in your other questions, `Session_Complete` looks like another excessive needless table.
Whatever info you want from this table, you can get from `Session` already.
So, no underneath inserts at all.

It seems you need to revise your database structure or - even better - post it here as a separate question and get a good advise on how to organize it properly.