# Inserting a blank row into a table to generate a foreign key or better way?

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to store the terms of a search. I've created a table "Searches" which stores each of the search terms in it's own field (bedrooms, baths, etc). So each row will contain one search.

On the advanced search form, users can select multiple search terms for a single field using an option select. I thought it would be wise to store each of these terms in a unique row of a related table for easy statistics reporting. I thought this way I could quickly report how many times a term is searched for. I also need to have the ability to save and regenerate the search query.

However if none of the terms searched are in the main table, I still need to generate a unique id to link it to the related table. So I would need to insert a blank row to generate the foreign key which I'm reluctant to do.

Is there a better way? I could store the multiple search terms questions in the primary table comma separated but it seems like it would be more difficult to pull them back out and count for statistics etc.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to insert a blank row?  You don't need to persist any of the records until the time comes to persist all of the records, right?

So as I understand it, your table layout is something like:

```
Table1
--------
ID
etc.

Table2
--------
ID
Table1ID
etc.
```

If that's the case, then the order of operations for inserting the data would look like this:

- Begin Transaction
- Insert into `Table1`
- [Get the last inserted ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/php-how-to-get-last-inserted-id-of-a-table)
- Insert into `Table2`
- Commit Transaction

Assuming I understand your UX correctly, this would all happen when the user submits the form.

Comment: There might not be any elements inserted into table 1, it might only be used for the overall id of the search and to tie together the multiple related tables.

Comment: @user1959500: Does the table design require a record in `Table1`, then?  It sounds like maybe the tables need to be re-designed if you're inserting non-entities into a table solely for an ID.  One idea might be to break up `Table1` into a `Table0` which is just the ID and maybe some other always-valid supporting values and a reduced `Table1` which has the sometimes-present values.  So `Table1` and `Table2` would both have an FK to `Table0` and would only have rows when needed.  (So always 1 row in `Table0` and 0-many rows in `Table1` and `Table2`.)  Just a thought, there are other options.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you,

it seems like you should have two tables:

```
search_term
-----------------
term_id
term
```

and

```
search
-----------------
search_id
term_id
```

then you can query search for all the terms and issue the SELECT statement.