# How to view last inserted value of auto increment field

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

In my database I have a field called `spaj_per` as an auto increment primary key.

How can I display the lastest inserted value in the field `spaj_per`. I tried this.

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "SuperAdmin", "***");
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db("sistem_pengurusan_fail",$con);

    $q = "SELECT MAX(id) AS spaj_per FROM unit_pengambilan"; 
    $result = mysql_query($q); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 

?>
<?php echo $row['spaj_per']; ?>
```

But it won't work.

Comment: Is "It won't work" the actual error message you're getting?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/php-how-to-get-last-inserted-id-of-a-table

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's `mysql_insert_id()` function

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

or like

```
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$q = "SELECT MAX(spaj_per) AS spaj_per FROM unit_pengambilan"; 
$result =mysql_query($q); 
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result); 

echo $row[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

```
For more reference use following link
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
<?
$q = "SELECT MAX(spaj_per) AS last_spaj_per FROM unit_pengambilan"; 
$result =mysql_query($q); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); 

 echo $row['last_spaj_per']; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);` Change to `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` and try