# Create a unique and seemingly random 5 character string

Tags: php, mysql, unique, uniqueidentifier

I'm trying to create a short, 5 or 6 character, invitation code that will be generated upon the creation of a "group" on my site.  The group info is stored in the group table.  Users wishing to join a group must have an invitation code--it isn't necessary that they know anything else.

Obviously, I need the invitation code to be unique, and I am hoping to generate unique strings without a double check, but figuring out the code has been difficult.  I've been reading dozens of SO questions and answers.  This is what I've come up with:

When inserting the group info, such as name, into the group table, the row is given a unique, auto-incrementing id, naturally.

> 1) Grab that id
>
> 2) add it to 1234
>
> 3) simply put the values next to eachother after converting the team name from base36 to base10 eg. "NewYorkYankees" is base10(3994055806027582482648) [1263399405580602758248264820130221060827])
>
> 4) convert to base 36
>
> 5) INSERT the code into the database

This is guaranteed to be unique for every group, right?  Zero chance of collision?  I say this because it isn't at all random; I start with something unique, and I keep it unique, never introducing random data.

I have a couple issues though, since group names are repeatable, how do I grab the row id upon creation/INSERTion?  This won't work, but it's where I'm at:

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM groups WHERE gname = :gname";
...
$uid = $result + '1234';
$hex = md5(":gname NOW()" . uniqid("$uid", true));
base_convert($hex, 10, 36);
intval($str, 36);

$query = "INSERT...";
```

Unique, short, but unpredictable without all the right pieces, which aren't available to users.

Comment: MD5 is never fully unique, some hashes can repeat themselves over time, this is called MD5 Collisions. Check the article out here: [MD5#Collision Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities)

Comment: you want unique code like password generated code?

Comment: Advait, I don't know what you mean by that question.

Comment: you want unique code which sometimes web site used in forgot password functionality...

Comment: No. I want a unique code that a group admin could give to a friend to give him access to the group without needing to know any other info, not even the group's name.

Comment: No. That's only one step among many.

Comment: Oh something unusual work David, i don't know sorry for that but try to find something for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO groups (gname, gadmin) VALUES (:gname, :gadmin)";
    $query_params = array( ':gname' => $trimmed['gname']
                           ':gadmin' => $userid );

    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        $gid = $db->lastInsertId();
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) {
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    // Use this library: https://github.com/ivanakimov/hashids.php
    $hashids = new Hashids\Hashids('this is my constant salt', 5,
                'abcdefghijklmnpqrstuvwxyz0123456789');

    $hash = $hashids->encrypt($gid);

    $query = "UPDATE groups SET invite = '$hash' WHERE id = '$gid'";
    ...
```

The library in question handles the heavy lifting.  It doesn't actually hash, per se.  It encrypts the input; since my row ids are unique, so is the encrypted result.  I have no need of decrypting the "hashes," but the option exists.  I can't strictly define the length, but I can set a minimum and have room to grow.  Also, as you can see, it allows me to define an 'alphabet' as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's described here [how to get the last inserted auto_increment value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/php-how-to-get-last-inserted-id-of-a-table).

After having an ID you need to use symmetric key encryption like AES with a secret key. It is guaranteed to be unique (as it can be transformed back to the original plaintext - which is called decryption).

You can tune the block size to get the desired length (in bits). With base64 the length will be a multiple of 4 (as 8bit characters are encoded in triplets, resulting in a 4 character block in base64).

Comment: I found that shortly before you posted it.  Thank you.  You gave a decent solution, but multiples of four, even at just 8 characters, is too long for my purpose.

Comment: @David May be only 4 printable characters (24bit) is enough. It will cover your IDs from 1 to 16 million - When you reach that much activity on your site you certainly want to rebuild it anyway. :) - Jokes aside you can get 6 printable characters if you drop the padding equal signs from the end of your base64 string (that will give you 40 bits which covers ids from 1 - 1,000,000,000,000).

Comment: I understand the low probability, but I feel like 4 characters makes guessing a valid value too easy.  Your answer is a good one, and fine for many application, but it doesn't offer my precisely what I'm asking for.  I don't particularly like marking my own answers as accepted.  So, even though what I found is more suited to my request, I may still accept your answer.

Comment: @David Self-accepted answers are totally all right. If the `Hashids` library does exactly what you need that's the most helpful answer for future visitors of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not concatenate the IP address or user-id of the person creating the group, and the time including milliseconds, and then MD5 or SHA-256 that to generate the string you publish? That will certainly be both unpredictable and nonrepeating.

Comment: It will be entirely too long and has possible collisions.

Comment: Possible collisions? How? It is practically impossible for two requests to arrive in the same millisecond from the same IP address, and collisions with MD5 difficult to create and unlikely - and SHA collisions haven't been discovered yet (and are mathematically extremely unlikely).

Comment: First of all, absolutely too long of a result.  Second, if those long results are somehow shortened, then the probability of collisions increases, especially when approaching my desired length.