# ID of an event (Fullcalendar)

Tags: javascript, mysql, fullcalendar

I need add an id to every single event from Fullcalendar, I found this http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/ but I don't know how, this id is
unique for every single event, because then I save the events in a Mysql database. Thanks

Comment: This id won't be unique because as stated in documentation repeating events should have the same event id. Whenever you are populating events in full calendar you can give id to every single event, however it's not mandatory.

Comment: But I need unique id, because later i will delete o edit the selected event and i need a id for do that, how can i do that, give an id when i am populating the calendar?

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution!
When you create any event, put your uniqe id here :

```
var shift = calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
        {
            id: shift_id,
            title: current_name,
            start: new Date(y, m, d + current_day, current_start_time_h, current_start_time_m),
            end: new Date(y, m, d + current_day, current_end_time_h, current_end_time_m),
            allDay: false
        }, true // make the event "stick"
        );
```

After that this listener append ID in DOM structure:

```
     eventAfterRender:function( event, element, view ) { 
$(element).attr("id","event_id_"+event._id);
},
```

To get all your events on a field:

```
console.log(calendar.fullCalendar('clientEvents'));
```

Now you have array of events, and all event are numbered in DOM structure!

Comment: `eventAfterRender` is now deprecated, use `eventPositioned` instead. [link](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventPositioned)

Answer (score 2):

**Clear Solution is**

When you fetch events with Ajax also assign "id" that coming from DB

**id:entry.id**

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: '/eventsJson', 
    type: 'GET', 
    data: { }, 
    error: function() {
        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
    } 
}).done(function (doc) { 

    var event = Array();
    $.each(doc, function(i, entry) {
        event.push({id:entry.id, title: entry.title, start: entry.start});
    });
```

**Event Click**

```
eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
               var title = prompt('Event Title:', event.title, { buttons: { Ok: true, Cancel: false} });

           if (title){
           event.title = title;

           var data = {
                'title':title
            };

           $.ajax({
             url: '/events/'+event.id,
             data: data,
             type: 'POST',
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function(response){
               if(response.status == 'success')
               $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);
             },
             error: function(e){
               alert('Error processing your request: '+e.responseText);
             }
           });
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The ID on an Event object is an optional field. You can return and use whatever you'd like to return from your server-side script. You can create a composite ID from a combination of fields...'calendarName_eventID' or simply use an eventID from your database. Not sure you want to expose your primary key like that, though (that's another issue in itself). Long story short...you get to create your own ID value.

You might want to have a look here: https://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=713

The thread deals with deleting a calendar event, but illustrates how the original poster was setting the ID on a callback from his/her save event.

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Thanks man but i think that post is too old and maybe that is the reason for it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is my solution way.
first I get the last id event from my DB and i plus 1 to the last id

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM calendar ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

$resul = mysql_fetch_row($sql);
$idActual = $resul[0];
$idActual = $idActual + 1;
?>
```

then i send the id to JS

```
var idActual = "<?php echo $idActual ?>";
```

and that's it.

Comment: Are you calling this separately when you go to create a new event? Can a user create more than one event before saving to the database?

Comment: Yes a user can create more than one event before it's save in the database

Comment: Without a postback, how are you populating each new `$idActual` that you need? I would think that in most cases you'd want to make an AJAX call to get the necessary id.

Comment: @BryanVillafañe,, I am trying to understand your solution. Does the ID generated in this way, would be equal to primary key ? for that specific column ? I am trying something similar here, I need to assign an ID to an event such that, my update query updates that specific entry associated with primary key rather than creating a new entry. Its been tricky because, primary key generates after saving and not sure how to capture in mysql/php.

Comment: @user5249203 - you can get it with `PDO::lastInsertId` or `mysqli::$insert_id` [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/how-do-i-get-the-last-inserted-id-of-a-mysql-table-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

As fletch mentions, you have to generate the ID for each new event in the DB or with the DB connection code in order to allow for concurrency. Bryan Villafañe uses similar approach, but here is my solution.

For FC javascript:

```
select: function(start) { //executed when clicked on a day
    var title = prompt('Event title:');
    if (title) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/events.php',
            data: 'title='+title+'&start='+moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            type: "POST",
            success: function(id) { 
                console.log(id); //used for debug
                if (!isNaN(id)){ //on success checks the result 
                    event = {    //and adds the event locally with the returned DB id.
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        team: team,
                        id: id
                    }//then renders the new event
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', event, true);
                }
            },
            error: function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    } //unselects the clicked day
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
}
```

This sends the date as a `YYYY-MM-DD` format since I only use allDay events, but you can update appropriately. Sending just `start` will result in epoch time with milliseconds.

The DB returns the ID of the row if the insert was successful, which is then assigned to the locally created event and is rendered. Here is the DB function:

```
$result = "Wrong parameter combination!";
if ($_POST[title]&&$_POST[start]) {
    $result = $db->exec("INSERT INTO events (title, start) VALUES ('$_POST[title]','$_POST[start]')");
    if($result==1){
        $result = $db->lastInsertRowID();
    }
}
echo $result;
```

Here I check for the two POST parameters and do the insert. If the insert was successful I get the last insert row ID and return it to the JS. Otherwise a error message is returned.

I'm using SQLite3 for my DB but the last inserted row for MySQL can be checked as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/how-do-i-get-the-last-inserted-id-of-a-mysql-table-in-php). There is a small chance for someone to insert another event between your insert and last row ID check, but unless you're running high traffic affair, you'll be OK.

Answer (score 1):

Each event already has its own unique id:

```
eventClick: function(event){
    alert(event._id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to set the param id in the prameters similar to this one:

```js
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  id: 'calendar',
  eventReceive: function(event) {
    alert(this.calendar.options.id);
  },
  eventDrop: function(event) {
    alert(this.calendar.options.id);
  },
  eventClick: function(event) {
    alert(this.calendar.options.id);
  },
  eventRender: function(event) {
    alert(this.calendar.options.id);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

setProp is recommended since v5 hope this helps someone else, I realised it was changing the id within the arg.event._def.id attr.

i used this in my ajax success as so;

```
          success: function (response_data) {
        arg.event.setProp("id", response_data['eventId'])}
```