# SQL parent - child relationship within same insert query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with has the possibility of a parent child relationship.
"parentid" has a foreign key to it's parent's "dataid" for example:

```
dataid     dataname     parentid
---------------------------------
1          example      NULL
2          record       NULL
3          foo          1
4          bar          1
```

In this example population "foo" and "bar" are children of "example".
Now i would like to insert multiple data records into this table, since dataid is auto incremented i would like to know if i can get this id after my insert without executing an extra query. So for example:

```
INSERT INTO table (dataname, parentid) VALUES 
    ( cat, NULL ), ( tiger, **dataid from cat** ), ( lion, **dataid from cat** );
```

To get this result:

```
dataid     dataname     parentid
---------------------------------
5          cat          NULL
6          tiger        5
7          lion         5
```

**ANSWER -- Thanks to PLB (and Simon Cambier):**

Still executing two queries after each other but i think this is solution will do.

```
/*first insert parent*/
INSERT INTO table (dataname, parentid) VALUES 
   ( cat, NULL );

/*insert children*/
INSERT INTO table (dataname, parentid) VALUES
   ( tiger, LAST_INSERT_ID() ), ( lion, LAST_INSERT_ID() );
```

Comment: This is the link you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/php-how-to-get-last-inserted-id-of-a-table

Comment: I think Simon is right - I think you'll need a minimum of two queries for what you are looking for.

Comment: [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)?

Comment: Thanks, for the quick response. I think Simon is right, therefor +1. When i got it working i will let you know!

Comment: I like PLB's since i can execute that right away without having go back to PHP. +1. Will post my answer below.