# How to get next auto increased id value?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a field 'Text'. The 'id' field is automatically increased when data is inserted. I run this query:

```
INSERT into answer (Text) VALUES ('Test');
INSERT into answer (Text) VALUES ('Test');
INSERT into answer (Text) VALUES ('Test');
INSERT into answer (Text) VALUES ('Test');
Delete From answer;
```

I need get future id (when I will insert next text). Can you help me with query, that take me number = 5 (but not 1, because 'id' automatically increased)?

Comment: Why do you need that? (You can't really do anything with that information safely.)

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/php-how-to-get-last-inserted-id-of-a-table

Comment: `@user2576078` please specify technology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *cannot* know the *next* auto_increment value. Well, probably not the way you think of it. You can only reliably obtain the *last* one used (by using [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)).

Some would probably tell you the other way: "this is easy, just take `LAST_INSERT_ID()+1`".

But this is a *bad* idea. Why? Because there will be *concurrent* access to your database. So you probably could guess the next ID in  the table. But not the next ID that will be attributed in *your transaction*.

<sub>(in addition, depending your DB setup, auto_increment step might be greater than 1 -- see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment)</sub>