# Idea for writing a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I've a table named `wp_bp_activity` with many columns that I think I should work with 4 of them for this issue: `id`, `type`, `item_id` and `date_recorded`.

**1 -** When someone post a new activity the `type` is `activity_update` and `item_id` is `0`

**2 -** When someone post a new comment on an activity its `type` is `activity_comment` and `item_id` is existed activity id in column `id`

**3 -** In both, `date_recorded` is the date of when data is inserted.

*There are also more `type`s in the table.*

But I wanna fetch only rows with `type` of `activity_update` that someone is recently replied to **or** are new (based on `date_recorded` I think)

Which I tried is :

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM wp_bp_activity as a, wp_bp_activity as b
WHERE
  ((b.type = 'activity_update') OR (b.type = 'activity_comment' AND b.item_id = a.id))
order by cast(a.date_recorded as datetime) desc
limit 0,20
```

That takes too long to be executed and ends with memory insufficient error.

Any help on this kind of query is appreciated.

***Update #1***

```
                        wp_bp_activity table

    id              type             item_id         date_recorded
|---------|-----------------------|-----------|--------------------------
|  12081  |   activity_comment    |   12079   |    2013-10-18 07:27:01
|---------|-----------------------|-----------|--------------------------
|  12080  |   activity_update     |     0     |    2013-10-18 07:26:40
|---------|-----------------------|-----------|--------------------------
|  12079  |   activity_update     |     0     |    2013-10-17 05:15:43
```

**Which rows I want from this table are these ids at this order:**

```
12079
12080
```

**What I don't want to get:**

`activity_comment` type

**In which order should rows fetch?**

As you can see the row with `activity_comment` type has an `item_id` with the value of `12079`. so `12079` is the latest activity that recently someone made a comment on it, and `12080` has no comments but is just posted. So I want both but at this order:

```
12079
12080
```

Comment: pls revo , see my updates... :)

Comment: My main question would be have you added decent indexing to the table? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that you are looking for "recent entries" (`WHERE type = 'activity_update' AND date_recorded > [threshold]`) and "entries having a recent reply, regardless of the entry's age" (`WHERE reply.type = 'activity_comment' AND reply.date_recorded > [threshold]`).

The first set is straightforward:

```
SELECT entries.*
FROM activity AS entries
WHERE type = 'activity_update' AND date_recorded > [threshold]
```

The second set is a bit less obvious:

```
SELECT entries.*
FROM activity AS entries
JOIN activity AS replies
    ON replies.item_id = entries.id
    AND replies.type = 'activity_comment'
WHERE
    entries.type = 'activity_update'
    AND replies.date_recorded > [threshold]
```

Putting it all together:

```
SELECT entries.*
FROM activity AS entries
LEFT JOIN activity AS replies -- LEFT JOIN, because an INNER JOIN would filter out entries without any reply
    ON  replies.item_id = entries.id
    AND replies.type = 'activity_comment'
WHERE
    entries.type = 'activity_update'
    AND (
        entries.date_recorded > [threshold]
        OR replies.date_recorded > [threshold] -- evaluates as FALSE if replies.date_recorded is NULL
    )
ORDER BY IFNULL(replies.date_recorded, entries.date_recorded) -- replies if not null, entries otherwise
```

*I am not proud of my poorly performing `ORDER BY` clause, I hope someone can suggest a better idea*

Comment: works!! but the problem is results have duplicate rows and if I use `distinct entries.*` results will differ!

Comment: In the end just change order by to: GROUP BY entries.id
ORDER BY IFNULL(max(replies.date_recorded), entries.date_recorded) desc

Comment: @TsanyoTsanev I used that grouping before but that didn't fix it. But your ORDER BY clause did the job! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should add one more field

```
id, type, item_id, commented_on, date_recorded
```

`::->> commented_on` will justifies that `item_id` comments on `commented_on`, here 12079 comments on 12080, so it may easy for you to get what you want

So your structure should look like :

```
   id             type            commented_on   item_id         date_recorded
|---------|-----------------------|-----------|-----------|--------------------------
|  12081  |   activity_comment    |   12080   |   12079   |    2013-10-18 07:27:01
|---------|-----------------------|-----------|-----------|--------------------------
|  12080  |   activity_update     |     0     |     0     |    2013-10-18 07:26:40
|---------|-----------------------|-----------|-----------|--------------------------
|  12079  |   activity_update     |     0     |     0     |    2013-10-17 05:15:43
```

Comment: I'm using buddypress so I can't do hard coding. thanks anyway!

Comment: you don't require any hard coding here, you have to just create a field from phpmyadmin , that require just a minute. and than it will easy to fire a query over that.

Comment: for inserting value to that field there is no need to hard coding?!

Comment: no , you need to just a edit insert query, nothing a hard at all

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something huge but what's wrong with just?:

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_bp_activity`
WHERE `type`='activity_update'
ORDER BY `date_recorded` ASC
LIMIT 0, 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have your JOIN condition in an OR clause.  This is an excellent example of why you should not use that syntax.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM wp_bp_activity as a JOIN wp_bp_activity as b ON b.item_id = a.id
WHERE
  ((b.type = 'activity_update') OR (b.type = 'activity_comment'))
order by cast(a.date_recorded as datetime) desc
limit 0,20
```

Comment: In your query all results must have `b.item = a.id` however in mine, `b.item = a.id` should only equals when `b.type = 'activity_comment'`

Comment: I need to order results based on activities which are recently get commented or posted. but in this way they're ordered by id!

Comment: Andy please see the update. I made my explanation easier to some extent.