# How to get primary key of last entry in an DB table

Tags: mysql, sql

In my PHP/MySQL application I have the following query to insert data in a table:

```
INSERT INTO `my_table` VALUES ('','$value1','$value2').
```

Where the first value is an auto incremented primary key.

Now, what I want to do is that immediately after this insert operation, I want to enter some data in another table `my_table2` where the `primary key` of the entry in `my_table` serves as `foreign key`.

Should I use a trigger or is there some way to get the primary key of last entry of a table.
Please answer with required code.

I am using **mysqli** and would like to keep this particular processing on database side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: how to get last inserted ID of a table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/php-how-to-get-last-inserted-id-of-a-table)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
 SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Answer (score 0):

After the insert statement you can fire another query:

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

and this will return one row with one column containing the id.

Docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

```
mysql> SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
        -> 195
```

This works per connection so there is no problem if another thread writes into the table. Your SELECT needs to be executed 'RIGHT AFTER'/'As the next query' after the insert query ran

An example:

```
$dbConnection = MyMagic::getMeTheDatabase("please");
$oSomeFunkyCode->createThatOneRowInTheDatabase($dbConnection);

$result = $dbConnection->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();");
// ... fetch that one value and you are good to go
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want it specifically for a table you can use following query:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT -1 as CurrentId FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOURDATABASE' AND TABLE_NAME = 'YOURTABLE'
```

Comment: What if another insert occurs in another session since the one you did in your session? (btw I did not downvote your answer)

Comment: one solution could be a routine where the query is run right before insert