# How to insert a id of a new row into another linking table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I've a table with the purpose of linking two other tables with foreign keys (table 3).

```
table1 = id, name
table2 = id, sport
table3 = fk_table1_id, dk_table2_id
```

I do server side code with php and i need a way to automatic insert a row into table 3 when a row is inserted into table2. 
But i dont know how to do a php query that will get the generated id of the new row in table2?
(The id of table one i do have stored in a php variable)
Im a looking at a smart stored procedure?

Comment: Use sql triggers.You can trigger an insert/delete query in sql when your php inserts into a table

Comment: but i can only get the values of the one table?

Comment: Depends on the PHP-side of your code. Mysql stores a @last_insert_id, which could be retrieved in PHP with a dedicated method (mysql_insert_id is deprecated). No need for Triggers, that would be overkill.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the last inserted ID of a MySQL table in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/how-do-i-get-the-last-inserted-id-of-a-mysql-table-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

**Steps to follow**:

- Insert a row into `table2`.
- Find the generated key from `table2` and assign it to a `PHP` variable.

```
    -- read this into a php variable, say, $last_key  
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

- Use the `$last_key` in `insert` statement for `table3`.

Answer (score 0):

You can Follow below Steps:

1) Make ID to AUTO_INCREMENT IN Table2

2) Create Store Procedure that work as below:

```
    A) INSERT Value to your Table2 :

    B) Increase ID value :  SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO VARIABLE; 

    C) Insert Value to your Table3   : use VARIABLE to get ID of Table2
```

Comment: Actually mysql not provide functionality of SEQUENCE like PostgreSQL. I change STEPS for mysql. check it