# SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() not generating correctly

Tags: php, mysql

im building a property website.

the current situation is that I have a property.php that includes many `isset _get` to determine the output. The property page is querying the property table and depending on the field allowing different types of input.  I am allowing uploads of multiple images which is in the images table. This is all working perfectly.

the problem is that due to the two tables, I need to insert two queries (I've defined tables and columns and fields into variables so I can reuse them in different pages and sites :) )

```
    $qry=mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table($col1,$col2,$col3,$col4,$col5,$col6,$col7,$col8,$col9,$col10,$col11,$col12,$col13,$col14)VALUES('$field','$field2','$field3','$field4','$field5','$field6','$field7','$field8','$field9','$field10','$field11','$field12','$field13','$field14')", $con);


if(!$qry)
{
die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}
else
{

include 'upload.php';
```

the upload.php does all the movement of the images and runs another query

```
$query="INSERT into images (`property`,`image`)  VALUES(SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$file_name'); ";
```

my problem is that the property field is never populated with the `last_insert_id()` and always 0.

basically I want to be able to track all the images uploaded to the id of the property table where it was inserted during the submit and I believe `last_insert_id()` would work to my needs - but not working with the current code.

before anyone talks about mysqli and pdo, let me mention that I will do it at a later stage.

Comment: You should use pdo for this. Refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/how-do-i-get-the-last-inserted-id-of-a-mysql-table-in-php

You can select that not directly in the query but calling the function after  first insert. So: 1)INSERT $table - 2)$lastinsert = mysql_insert_id(); - 3) INSERT images

Comment: [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php). [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use select before `LAST_INSERT_ID()` on inserting try

```
$query="INSERT into images (`property`,`image`)  VALUES( LAST_INSERT_ID(),'$file_name'); ";
```

**OR** you can try with `mysql_insert_id()`

```
$qry=mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table($col1,$col2,$col3,$col4,$col5,$col6,$col7,$col8,$col9,$col10,$col11,$col12,$col13,$col14)VALUES('$field','$field2','$field3','$field4','$field5','$field6','$field7','$field8','$field9','$field10','$field11','$field12','$field13','$field14')", $con);
if(!$qry) {
  die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
}
else {
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();
include 'upload.php';
```

then upload.php query will be

```
$query="INSERT into images (`property`,`image`)  VALUES('$last_id','$file_name'); ";
```

Comment: this actually solves the initial issue, but I see that it doesn't resolve my problem. when i run the 2nd query first time, it takes the id of property, but if i upload multiple pictures the 2nd query run 2nd time, will generate id of 2nd query and not 1st query. i hope that's clear.

Comment: ok then save your first id in table and get back the inserted id for multiple queries

Comment: sorry, i don't quite get that.

1st query is for properties table 2nd query is for images table
1st query runs . properties table fields are populated
if successful, 2nd query runs
2nd query gets last id correct for the 1st insert
on 2nd insert part of the array, it last id becomes the id of 2nd query not first. tried mysql_insert_id as well, same issue

Comment: if each time page refrehing you will get a new last id so what's problem. if you do multiple upload then above variable $last_id will be return same

Comment: the last id, should only be of query 1,  not of query 2...

the reason is that the id of property table will be inserted to track all the images from that property in the images table

Comment: hmm. sorry rakesh, i didn't try the variable bit, will try and let you know

Comment: doesn't seem to like it 

Notice: Undefined variable: last_id in D:\xampp\htdocs\Websites\mindia\upload.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined variable: last_id in D:\xampp\htdocs\Websites\mindia\upload.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined variable: last_id in D:\xampp\htdocs\Websites\mindia\upload.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined variable: last_id in D:\xampp\htdocs\Websites\mindia\upload.php on line 13

Comment: never mind. it works. just noticed I had included upload.php twice... thanks a lot.