# How to Get last Insert Id in php without insert any data?

Tags: php, mysql

I need the `last inserted record` in PHP without insert any data I need the `id before insert` any data .

Comment: select max(id) + 1 from your table, that will be the id you want.

Comment: Select Max(id) from table_name

Comment: `mysqli_insert_id($con)`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the last inserted ID of a MySQL table in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/how-do-i-get-the-last-inserted-id-of-a-mysql-table-in-php)

Comment: @Hoque MD Zahidul i dont know why you need this but you most likly will run into race conditions with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope this is what you're looking for

```
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Hope this helps you out

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM your_table_name
```

Or using PDO

```
PDO::lastInsertId
```