# Select highest ID of database and use the result in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I try to create a new folder for each new registration but I do have troubles with naming them after their unique registration id.

In my database each new user gets a userid.
To select the latest userid I use the SQL Statement

```
$sql = "SELECT max(userid) FROM User";
```

So far so good, PHPMYADMIN shows me the correct result, but I don't know how to save this single result in a variable in PHP.
Read through the PHP manual and tried the different fetch options but either I didn't get it or the result was different from what I wanted.

Right now I can only print all the results, but not the one I want with this:

```
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
  echo $row['userid'] . "<br />";
}
```

The goal is to get this thing to work:

```
mkdir("uploads/$userid", 0755, true);
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm getting really frustrated with this!

**EDIT:**
Okay went for the easy route and named the directory after a hash from the email.
Still it would interest me: 
If I use `$sql = "SELECT max(userid) FROM User";`
How do I bind the result to a variable in PHP?

Comment: Are you running the SAME query?

Comment: `SELECT max(userid) as uid  FROM User` you can also add an `as`  to your statement to guarantee name of result

Comment: The SELECT statement selects the correct value but I can't use it somehow. Is there a way to store the output of my query in a variable? Tried the different pdo fetch things but didn't really work

Answer (score 4):

If you insert a record into a table that contains an AUTO_INCREMENT column, you can obtain the value stored into that column by calling the **mysql_insert_id()** function.

When a new AUTO_INCREMENT value has been generated, you can also obtain it by executing a **SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()** statement with mysql_query() and retrieving the value from the result set returned by the statement.

You can also reference this post:

[How do I get the last inserted ID of a MySQL table in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/how-do-i-get-the-last-inserted-id-of-a-mysql-table-in-php)

Comment: This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0 instead use PDO::lastInsertId()

Comment: Thanks for the answer, tried to use this before but all I got was 0 as a result. Right now I have put the "echo $db->lastInsertId();" under my query but it is also only showing a 0.      Here is a pastebin of the code, maybe you see the error? http://pastebin.com/8TBCPzn9

Answer (score 1):

So instead of echoing the result out, why not use it to make that dir?

```
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
 mkdir("uploads/$row['userid']");
}
```

Comment: The echo was just for me to see if the code works. Tried the code but there were some weird errors.

Comment: He is taking max userid from database that returns single response which is what he wants