# How to retrive last inserted auto generated id for the same table on different php-html page

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am creating a sign up form using HTML5/CSS3/PHP/MySql  that will have following columns:

Firstname, Lastname, Email, Password ( to be filled on Web form-1)

Username, country, Age, SecurityQues, SecurityAns, Mobile (to be filled on web-form 2).

there is only one table named user_record for all the fields and it has a user_id that is auto generated and auto increment when the web form 1 is executed, and it is also the primary key for the table.

I am using insert query for web form 1 and update query for web form 2. but the second form's data cannot be submitted until it has UserId generated in the web form 1.

I tried to retrieve it using lastInsertId(); but it is not working as it returns the id only when the insertion is done on the same page so it works on form 1 but not on form 2.

there is only one table being used on two different web pages. on one insertion is being done and user_id is being generated. 
On the another update query will be performed to update the remaining fields of the row created in the first form. for that form 2 needs primary key which is not available.

Can any one help me and tell me how to retrieve last UserId on the form 2 so that the data can be filled on the same row that user just created on form 1.

following is the code snippet for both form 1 and form 2.

Form 1 PHP Snippet:

```
 <?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "myDB";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$db", $username, $password);


$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if(isset($_POST['sign_up-btn'])){
    session_start();

    $first_name = ($_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = ($_POST['last_name']);
    $email_id = ($_POST['email_id']);
    $password = ($_POST['password']);
    $password2 = ($_POST['password2']);

    if($password == $password2){
        $password = md5($password);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO user_record(first_name, last_name, email, password) VALUES('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email_id', '$password')";
        $conn->exec($sql);
        $_SESSION['message'] =  "You are almost done";
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
        header("location: pro.php");

    }else{
        $_SESSION['message'] =  "Password do not match";
    }
}
 $conn = null;
 ?>
```

PHP Script of form 2 is:

```
 <?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "myDB";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$db", $username, $password);


$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

if(isset($_POST['sub_btn'])){
    session_start();

    $user_name = ($_POST['user_name']);
    $sel_cont = ($_POST['sel_cont']);
    $age = ($_POST['age']);
    $sec_que = ($_POST['sec_que']);
    $sec_ans = ($_POST['sec_ans']);
    $mob_num = ($_POST['mob_num']);
    $con_code = ($_POST['con_code']);

    $id = $conn->lastInsertId();


    $sql = "UPDATE user_record SET user_name = '$user_name', country = '$sel_cont', 
    age = '$age', security_ques = '$sec_que', security_ans = '$sec_ans', 
    mobile_num = '$mob_num', c_code = '$con_code' WHERE user_id = '$id' ";

    $conn->exec($sql);
    $_SESSION['message'] =  "Welcome";
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name;
    header("location: home.php");

}

$conn = null;
 ?>
```

Plz tell me how to update the same row with the data of second form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the last inserted ID of a MySQL table in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/how-do-i-get-the-last-inserted-id-of-a-mysql-table-in-php)

Comment: Did you try using Ajax, or if you don't intent to use javascript, setting the ID in session?

Comment: Try this `SELECT MAX(id)  FROM table ;`

Comment: If you're using PDO, use PDO::lastInsertId.

Comment: @SnakeEye no its not the duplicate as I am trying to retrieve the Id on different script no on the same script or form or web page. only table is same for both tables so need user_id on both pages which is generated on the first one but not available on the second one.

Comment: @BojanRadaković I am not proficient in AJAX. so don't know how to do it

Comment: @VasimVanzara i tried it but the same result it returns the last id created on first form but not for the second one.

Comment: do you need last updated record id?

Comment: @pgill you can try with `header("location: second.php?id=" . $id);` and use `$_GET['id']` to get the value

Comment: @BojanRadaković I am trying session variable now if it doesn't work then I '' try this also. thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, the second form can't be submited if does not exists first record inserted.

I supose that second forms is already on the client browser.

You must to use session capabilities, on first form you must to set the lastInsertId() on a session variable.

Later, on form2 submit, the php can retrive the session variable before the UPDATE. If the session variable containing the lastInsertID is not set, means that the client has not submited first form.

Comment: @XPerez on the first form after filling first_name, last_name, email_id and  password when user submits only then the second form is available.   Can you please explain bit more what you said. then I ll try it.

Answer (score 0):

As the @XPerez mentioned I needed to use session variables. so on the first web form I added following line before header statement:

```
 $_SESSION['user_id'] = $conn->lastInsertId();
```

and on the second form I added following statement before Update statement

```
 $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

and it did the trick. Session variables can used on different web pages through out the single session. On the first page when session started I stored the id of the insertion statement into a session variable and then use it on the second page.