# Getting the primary key ID of the last inserted row to run multiple insert operations

Tags: php, mysql

I have to run multiple `INSERT` statements one after the other, but I need to retrieve the primary key of the last inserted row in between, to use in the next `INSERT` statement. I understand I can do this with `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`, but I'm not too sure how to use it in my code to store inside the php variable.

```
function addItem($name, $category, $rating, $user){
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO items (id, category, api, name, api_id) VALUES ('', '". $category ."', '', '". $name ."', '')";
    $pdo->query($sql);
    // $item_id = ???
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ratings (id, user, item, rating) VALUES ('', '". $user ."', '". $item_id ."', '". $rating ."')";
    $pdo->query($sql);
    Database::disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Documentation of the PDO methods shows this: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: If your primary key column is set to auto increment then no need of adding it in insert query

Comment: try here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/how-do-i-get-the-last-inserted-id-of-a-mysql-table-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PDO's `lastInsertId` method like this

```
$item_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: this works for fields with `auto increment` not `primary key`

Answer (score 1):

### Try this:

```
function addItem($name, $category, $rating, $user){
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO items (id, category, api, name, api_id) VALUES ('', '". $category ."', '', '". $name ."', '')";
    $pdo->query($sql);

    // $item_id = ???
    $item_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO ratings (id, user, item, rating) VALUES ('', '". $user ."', '". $item_id ."', '". $rating ."')";
    $pdo->query($sql);
    Database::disconnect();
}
```