# Sql insert id from one table to entry in another

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database. When I insert record to first table I need to take `id` that automatically generate by Mysql and add it to a new record in 2nd table.

So I need to take `id` from this record:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO movies (title, year, format);
```

and put it inside this record:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO actors(name, last_name, movi_id);
-----------------------------------------------^
                                              HERE
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the last inserted ID of a MySQL table in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/how-do-i-get-the-last-inserted-id-of-a-mysql-table-in-php)

Comment: @jaikrexe You need to use mysqli_insert_id() function to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below in-built PHP function for getting id from your last Insert Query:

```
mysqli_insert_id();
```

Your code must be like below to resolve your issue:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO movies (title, year, format) VALUES ($title, $year, 
$format)";    
$movi_id = mysqli_insert_id();
$sql = "INSERT INTO actors(name, last_name, movi_id) VALUES ($name, 
$last_name, $movi_id)";
```

It's better if you can write above query in **Prepared Statements** to make it more **secure**:

```
// prepare and bind Movies Query
$queryMovies = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO movies (title, year, format) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$queryMovies->bind_param("sss", $title, $year, $format);

// execute Movies Query
$queryMovies->execute();

// Get last inserted Id of Movies Query
$movi_id = $queryMovies->insert_id;

// prepare and bind Actors Query
$queryActors = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO actors (name, last_name, movi_id) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$queryActors->bind_param("sss", $name, $last_name, $movi_id);

// execute Actors Query
$queryActors->execute();

// Close Connections
$queryMovies->close();
$queryActors->close();
```

Comment: Downvoted because while this answer isn't technically wrong (although it's not actually executing queries), it says nothing of escaping data or using prepared statements and doesn't use a transaction for something that clearly should be atomic.

Comment: @ChelseaUrquhart If by helping someone I get downvoting then I am ready for it :)

Comment: Apologies... I wouldn't have downvoted it just for the lack of a transaction but SQL injection vulnerabilities are extremely dangerous, insanely easy to avoid, and should not be spread in examples that could easily be copy-pasted by the OP or others with the same question.

Comment: @ChelseaUrquhart Yes you have done right thing then. We only learn from criticism. I appreciate that you spend time to ascertain the issue and revealed me the correct approach. Thanks!

Comment: @ChelseaUrquhart I have updated my answer with prepared statements. Please check. Thanks again for showing me the right way :)

Comment: @ChelseaUrquhart Thanks a lot once again :)