# how to get last insert in two table at a single time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is the query I tried,

```js
$result = "INSERT INTO task_assign(assigned_to,assigned_by,end_on,task_title,task_desc,priority,task_status,history_assigned) VALUES('$assignTo','$assignBy','$endOn','$title','$description','$priority','$status','$assignTo')";

mysql_query("INSERT INTO notification(title,description,priority,category_id,assignment_type,sender_id,receiver_id,date_time)
    VALUES('$title', '$description', '$priority', '$category_id', '1', $assigassignTonBy, $assignTo, NOW())
    ");
    //this return only task_assign
    echo $rowId = mysql_insert_id();
```

How can I get the last insert id from the table?

Comment: task_assign means what?, which column name?

Comment: task_assign means what ?, which column name ?

Comment: you are complete open for sql injection attacks, please consider to use preparet statements

Comment: I can't speak for others, but I simply ignore questions relating to PHP's archaic, insecure, and deprecated mysql_ API

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure there is column which is 'AUTO INCREMENT' with 'PRIMARY KEY'.

2) `mysql_query` has been deprecated. You can use object oriented approach PDO or Prepared statement, Mysqli. You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/how-do-i-get-the-last-inserted-id-of-a-mysql-table-in-php) too.

3) You can use `mysqli_insert_id()` OR `PDO::lastInsertId()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ideas to try.

1. Run the first INSERT, then immediately following that call mysql_insert_id() to retrieve the task_assign ID. Then follow the same steps for the next query. Run the query and then immediately call the mysql_insert_id() method. If you have AUTO_INCREMENT set in each table you should get the IDs which can be assigned to separate variables.

   Resource: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

   Be sure to review the Return Values and Notes sections of that page.
2. Alternatively, you could create more queries to grab each ID from the two tables (assuming you haven't altered the primary key in some way at one point or another). For example:

   ```
   SELECT task_assignID FROM task_assign ORDER BY task_assignID DESC
   SELECT notificationID FROM notification ORDER BY notificationID DESC
   ```