# how to create post_id for a new post in social website

Tags: php, mysql, web

I want to create id for the new post, such as **00001**,**00002**, however,
at the same time I need to retrieve the post_id to name the picture URL `xxx/00001_1.jpg`. So should I implement it with `mysql(auto_increment)` or php/java API?

Comment: I think that ids should have no meaning beyond the scope of the database, so just have an autoincrementing id, and a unique image filepath/name. Trust the database to tell you which image belongs to which post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run two queries at a time
1) insert the post to mysql database than get the id of last modified row.
2) update that particular row with the help of the Id that you fetched and execute update table command at that particular row Id with new name of 001.jpg
Comment if you need a real working code

And auto_increment will give you numbers from 0 too so on. If you need numbers like that use php base_convert()

I am continuing with the code example I Said.

**First Query be like**

```
INSERT into table (name, post) VALUES ('$NAME', '$POST_STRING') ;
```

$lastID = mysqli_insert_id($con);

**Second Update query for inserting image will be like **

```
UPDATE table SET img = '$lastID' WHERE Id = '$lastID'
```

Comment: Happy to help  may be I can get an up vote from you

Comment: I would like to do that, however, my reputation is less than 15 points and I could not vote now..

Answer (score 0):

For the schema yes, just use auto_increment.

I'm unsure about in java but there are functions in php to return the of the last item inserted:
[How do I get the last inserted ID of a MySQL table in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/how-do-i-get-the-last-inserted-id-of-a-mysql-table-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use auto-increment because auto-increment always starts with 1. And you are using 00001. So, you have to add id manually.

First of all get last inserted id. and when you will insert new data you have to do +1 with `last_inserted_id` - like this:

```
$last_inserted_id=SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

at insert time use last_inserted_id and +1.