# php auto incrementing ID in mySQL differs from the stored one

Tags: php, mysql

So on my web page i have a database connection setup.
Once a user posts a comment on the web page it adds the comment to the database and a column in the database called ID gets incremented by 1.
This ID serves as the primary key for the each row in the database.
So when the user wants to remove a comment it checks the database for the comment that has matching primary key.

My current solution is this.

add the comment to the database

the database adds the ID

get the ID from the database

store it together with the comment in an array

When a user clicks delete comment check if the comment ID matches the ID in the database.

My problem with this is that it feels weird calling the database to add the comment and then call the database again to get the comment ID.

Is there any better solution to this?

Comment: You should check the SQL and php doc on how to get the last inserted Id.

Comment: do you've any code to share with us?

Comment: Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/how-do-i-get-the-last-inserted-id-of-a-mysql-table-in-php if you are using an auto increment column type.

Comment: Also, decide what you mean by 'DELETE'. Does a deleted record permanently disappear from the data set, or does it just become invisible to end users?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: *"My problem with this is that it feels weird calling the database to add the comment and then call the database again to get the comment ID.

Is there any better solution to this?"*  Yes but not in MySQL use PostgreSQL instead which supports `INSERT INTO ... RETURNING *` which insertes the returns all values back to the application without needing to do a extra select to fetch the extra infromation like increments and or defualt column values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I've added some code based on your question. Let's say you've a table called **comments** where you're inserting some values and as the `id` is an auto incremented field so it is inserted automatically with your passed data. So if you try with **php** and **mysql** then after your insert operation you can easily get the last inserted id without doing another extra query for inserted id using `$conn->insert_id`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO comments(commenter, comment)
VALUES ('John', 'How are you?')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $last_id = $conn->insert_id;
    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

**REF.:** http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: Hey downvoter, any specific reason for voting it down?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `mysql_insert_id()` function to get record inserd ID or similar function, depending on which driver you are using. But there should be a special function for this.

You do not need to run another query.

Comment: The last thing to recommend I would have thought is a `mysql_` function, the whole API is deprecated and removed in PHP 7.

Comment: It is not a recommendation to use this driver. This is just as an example of this function. The author can use mysqli_ or PDO or any other driver he needs. I just let him know that there is a special function to retrieve the last insert ID.